Partial upgrade notice?
I was running updates today in the GUI, not what I normally do. And I got a thing saying it could only do a partial upgrade. If I do it from the command line it seems it's almost all good.
I think I ^C an update a while ago, but it has been working fine until now
I have tried some reconfigures with dpkg and tried to fix dependencies. I looked at the output of the sudo apt upgrade and it looks clean with 2 held back but that doesn't seem to be the problem.
I've done everything I know and still am getting this error
I am running Ubuntu 23.10

The problem was fixed by manly removing (and im about to install latest version) of a game (widelands)
